# web api JSON Model is null

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

When I sending a json response back to my api the model is report null and does not update.  I have set the Content-Type to application/json

**Request**:

> [{"SurveyID": "55","QuestionID": "4","Responses": 6},{"SurveyID": "55","QuestionID": "12","Responses": "1"}]

**Controller**:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri] Response response)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (NPSEntities entities = new NPSEntities())
            {
                entities.Responses.Add(response);
                entities.SaveChanges();
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Invalid Model");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

**Model**:

```
public partial class Response
{
    public int ResponseID { get; set; }
    public string SurveyID { get; set; }
    public string QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string Responses { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifyDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: First problem I see is that you're sending an array of objects but your method is only expecting a single object. Try changing your method signature to `IEnumerable<Response> response`.

Comment: thank you.  I have figured it out instead of using `IEnumerable<Response> response` I used `List<Response> response` and I De-serialized the Object